# Firebase Functions onRequest not triggering

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase function `host` set up to run whenever the user visits a Firebase Hosting URL, but nothing ever gets logged (the function is not being triggered)

`index.js`:

```
exports.host = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(">>>> FUNCTION TRIGGERED!")
  res.send(">>>> GOT IT")
})
```

I have it set up like so in my `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "destination": "/index.html",
        "function": "host"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are the emulator function logs when I run it locally (the emulator is running on `localhost:4001`, and the web app is running on `localhost:5000`. When I visit `localhost:5000`, nothing logs, even though the function is said to be initialized.

```
12:53:42W
ui
Emulator UI unable to start on port 4000, starting on 4001 instead.
12:53:42I
ui
Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
12:53:43I
functions
Watching "**firebase-project**/functions" for Cloud Functions...
12:53:43I
functions
http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/****/us-central1/host).
12:53:43I

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4001 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4001/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hosting   │ localhost:5000 │ n/a                             │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
 
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2603 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.0fec40ca.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 200 53148 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/css/2.85b71462.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 200 43004 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.3cf6a16f.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 216613 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/js/2.8f67d3af.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3343005 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /faceapi/weights/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-weights_manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 26548 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /faceapi/weights/face_landmark_68_model-weights_manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 7889 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/media/Create%20visuals%20for%20remote%20teaching..9fdce83b.png HTTP/1.1" 200 30230 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/media/homepage_background.1c84776f.png HTTP/1.1" 200 72508 "http://localhost:5000/static/css/main.0fec40ca.chunk.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /static/media/homepage_laptop.a18abdeb.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6106290 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /faceapi/weights/face_landmark_68_model-shard1 HTTP/1.1" 200 356840 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /faceapi/weights/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-shard2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1422653 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
12:54:19I
hosting
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2020:04:54:19 +0000] "GET /faceapi/weights/ssd_mobilenetv1_model-shard1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4194304 "http://localhost:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
```

Is this correct way of setting up functions? It's my first time working with them so I'm having a hard time debugging this. For some context, I'm trying to dynamically modify the OpenGraph meta tags depending on the URL, and I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@jalalio/dynamic-og-tags-in-your-statically-firebase-hosted-polymer-app-476f18428b8b

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting rewrite looks incorrect.  I suggest taking a look at the documentation for how to [configure a rewrite to a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions).  It shouldn't have a "destination", just "source" and "function".  Also, if you intend to serve the URI "/" through the function, you should not have an index.html present at all in your public folder, otherwise it will get served first.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the answer! I need my index.html to be in my public folder since I still want to display it; all I really want to do is modify its meta tags depending on what URL it is accessed from. There aren't multiple html files, but there are multiple routes in my React application, and for each of these routes I want to do some server-side processing to figure out what information should be in the meta tags.

Comment: You can't use Cloud Functions to intercept or alter the handling of static content served by Firebase Hosting.  Each request is either handled by Hosting statically, or Cloud Functions dynamically, but never both.